# Is there a cache is async task? My results aren't changing when they should

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am using async task in android to get json from an online database to check if a users password and user name are correct.

Each time I test on my phone the json string for "status" is always no and never yes even when I type in the correct info.

But when I test it in my browser with the same info I type in my phone I get the right json results. It is always returning "no"

Async task:

```
public class ReadLogInJSON extends AsyncTask
<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;

    public ReadLogInJSON(Context context)
    {
         c = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        //decode json here
        try{                
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

            String status = json.getString("status");
            Log.d("BeforeIf", status);
            if(status.equals("no")){
                //toast logIN failed
                Log.d("logIN-no", status);
                String message = "Log In Failed";
                Toast.makeText(c,  message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                //get userName
                Log.d("logIN-yes", "correct");
                //get user ID

                //set preferences

                //launch normal activity
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }        
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a cache is async task?

No, the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) does not cache its results. You can see this yourself by looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java).